# Image size fiz on all breakpoints mobile, tablet and website

Tags: html, css

we have an image which is upload from mobile but one problem is there --
we want, which image we upload from a mobile on a web, show image normal without blur, stretch and small size
we want the image to fit in div and show image good quality on web, mobile and tablet

Comment: add meta viewport tag

Comment: Thanks! @ShivanshPotdar but meta tag is not a solution we want an image, "height width" same as it is on mobile, tablet and website.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly. You're looking to make the uploaded image fit a certain area in your page regardless if it's viewed on mobile, tablet or desktop.

If that's what you're after, you can wrap the image and give a width of `100%`. See below example.

```
    .img-wrapper {
      width: 100%; /*Adjust accordingly. Now it's set to full width*/
    }

    .img-wrapper img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
```

HTML

```
    <div class="img-wrapper">
          <img src="" /> <!-- uploaded image -->
    </div>
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xom7q5cd/)**